# Create new column that merges two columns

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have 100 files with similar format (shown below). I want to add a new column to every files that combines the column `mir` and `seq` separated by an `_`
This has to be done automatically for all files. All my files have these names:

```
Miraligner_240G.txt.mirna
Miraligner_239R.txt.mirna
....
```

They differ between _ and .txt.mirna

My input files look like this:

```
seq                     name          freq  mir           start end mism add    t5  t3       s5         s3    DB  ambiguity
TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT seq_100006_x2   2   hsa-miR-143-3p  61  81  6AT u-TT    0   0   AGTCTGAG    GCTCAGGA    miRNA   1
GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTA seq_100012_x2   2   hsa-miR-10a-5p  22  43  1GT u-A 0   u-G TATATACC    TGTGTAAG    miRNA   1
GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG seq_100013_x35  35  hsa-miR-10a-5p  22  44  1GT 0   0   0   TATATACC    TGTGTAAG    miRNA   1
TTAGGGCCCTGGCTCCATCT    seq_100019_x13  13  hsa-miR-1296-5p 16  35  0   0   0   u-CC    TGGGTTAG    CTCCTTTA    miRNA   1
GTGAACGGGCGCCATCCCGAGGCTT   seq_100029_x2   2   hsa-miR-887-3p  48  72  0   0   0   d-CTT   TGGAGTGA    GAGGCTTT    miRNA   1
ACCCGGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG  seq_10002_x5    5   hsa-miR-10a-5p  23  44  5GT 0   d-T 0   TATATACC    TGTGTAAG    miRNA   1
CAACGGAATCCCAAAAGCAGCTGAAAA seq_100031_x3   3   hsa-miR-191-5p  16  39  24AT    u-AAA   0   d-T CGGGCAAC    GCTGTTGT    miRNA   1
TAGTGCAATATTGCTTATAGGGTAT   seq_100033_x2   2   hsa-miR-454-3p  64  86  0   u-AT    0   0   TGAGTAGT    GGGTTTTG    miRNA   1
CAACGGAATCCGAAAAGCAGCTG seq_100037_x16  16  hsa-miR-191-5p  16  38  12GC    0   0   0   CGGGCAAC    GCTGTTGT    miRNA   1
```

My output files should look like this:

```
mir_seq                                  seq                        name          freq  mir           start end mism add t5 t3       s5         s3    DB  ambiguity
hsa-miR-143-3p_TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT   TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT    seq_100006_x2   2   hsa-miR-143-3p  61  81  6AT u-TT    0   0   AGTCTGAG    GCTCAGGA    miRNA   1
....
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk` you can add a column containing values of column 1 and 4 as:

```
awk '{print $4"_"$1, $0}' filename
```

`OFS` will print the value of output field separator variable.

On piping the output to `column -t`:

```
mir_seq                                     seq                          name            freq  mir              start  end  mism  add    t5   t3     s5        s3        DB     ambiguity
hsa-miR-143-3p_TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT      TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT      seq_100006_x2   2     hsa-miR-143-3p   61     81   6AT   u-TT   0    0      AGTCTGAG  GCTCAGGA  miRNA  1
hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTA      GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTA      seq_100012_x2   2     hsa-miR-10a-5p   22     43   1GT   u-A    0    u-G    TATATACC  TGTGTAAG  miRNA  1
hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG      GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG      seq_100013_x35  35    hsa-miR-10a-5p   22     44   1GT   0      0    0      TATATACC  TGTGTAAG  miRNA  1
hsa-miR-1296-5p_TTAGGGCCCTGGCTCCATCT        TTAGGGCCCTGGCTCCATCT         seq_100019_x13  13    hsa-miR-1296-5p  16     35   0     0      0    u-CC   TGGGTTAG  CTCCTTTA  miRNA  1
hsa-miR-887-3p_GTGAACGGGCGCCATCCCGAGGCTT    GTGAACGGGCGCCATCCCGAGGCTT    seq_100029_x2   2     hsa-miR-887-3p   48     72   0     0      0    d-CTT  TGGAGTGA  GAGGCTTT  miRNA  1
hsa-miR-10a-5p_ACCCGGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG       ACCCGGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG       seq_10002_x5    5     hsa-miR-10a-5p   23     44   5GT   0      d-T  0      TATATACC  TGTGTAAG  miRNA  1
hsa-miR-191-5p_CAACGGAATCCCAAAAGCAGCTGAAAA  CAACGGAATCCCAAAAGCAGCTGAAAA  seq_100031_x3   3     hsa-miR-191-5p   16     39   24AT  u-AAA  0    d-T    CGGGCAAC  GCTGTTGT  miRNA  1
hsa-miR-454-3p_TAGTGCAATATTGCTTATAGGGTAT    TAGTGCAATATTGCTTATAGGGTAT    seq_100033_x2   2     hsa-miR-454-3p   64     86   0     u-AT   0    0      TGAGTAGT  GGGTTTTG  miRNA  1
hsa-miR-191-5p_CAACGGAATCCGAAAAGCAGCTG      CAACGGAATCCGAAAAGCAGCTG      seq_100037_x16  16    hsa-miR-191-5p   16     38   12GC  0      0    0      CGGGCAAC  GCTGTTGT  miRNA  1
```

Since `awk` don't have inline editing option, you will have to use `gawk` for inline editing. Using `awk`, you can write the output to temporary file and then move/copy/rename it to original file name.

For using the command in multiple file:

```
for i in Miraligner_*.txt.mirna; do
    awk '{print $4"_"$1, $0}' "$i" | column -t;
done
```

If you are using `gawk` and interested in doing inline editing, use `gawk -i inplace`

---

Using `perl`:

```
perl -ane 'print "$F[3]_$F[0] $_";' filename | column -t
```

If you want to write to file, use `-i` option:

```
perl -ane 'print "$F[3]_$F[0] $_";' -i filename
```

Separate all the input fields and the appended column (field) with `\t`:

```
perl -ane '$"="\t"; print "$F[3]_$F[0] @F\n";' -i filename
```

---

If you want your output in your file in proper tabular form:

```
for i in Miraligner_*.txt.mirna; do
    awk '{print $4"_"$1, $0}' "$i" | column -t > temp && mv temp "$i";
done
```

This will give output separated into proper column in your file. For this, you won't need inline editing option.

---

Thanks to @EdMorton for correcting my mistakes.

Comment: How to you do this for all files?        I tries this: for f in Miraligner_*.txt.mirna do awk '{print $4"_"$1 OFS $0}' "$f" > "MiralignerMerge${f#}" done

Comment: Does your for loop print to the same file?

Comment: @BioMan as I mentioned, if you want to do inline editing, either use `gawk` or `perl` for it. That is because `awk` don't have inline editing option. If you want, I can add answer in `perl`.

Comment: Please show me the perl answer. I will try gawk as well

Comment: Is it possible to not overwrite the input file with your latest for-loop?

Comment: @BioMan just don't use `mv temp $i` since that will replace the input file with the temp file. But then using `column -t > temp` will also be of no use. I recent for-loop will replace the input file with the output you want in a proper tabular form. Else you will have to manually adjust the column width if you want to set output in tabular form.

Comment: @BioMan your last comment is not clear to me. Can you please explain what you mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82409/discussion-between-bioman-and-rakholiya-jenish).

Comment: Use `,` instead of hard-coding `OFS` in the awk command and always use `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file` so the `mv` only occurs if `cmd` succeeded, otherwise you can zap your input file. Also ALWAYS quote your shell variables (use `"$i"`, not `$i`) unless you are trying to achieve a specific effect by not doing so and fully understand all of the effects. `gawk -i` is to include a library. `gawk -i inplace` is to include the inplace editing library.